# Should questions where OP replaces their question with vandalism be flagged?

Tags: support, questions, flags

The user asking a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203737/) later [replaced their question with vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69203737/3). Should I flag the question such that the user can be educated on how to behave better?

Comment: Note that [the OP has been educated by a mod before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67299743/struggling-to-structure-an-sql-query#comment118961545_67299743)

Comment: This is honestly when the "last seen" metric would be really useful, so we can see the OP has indeed seen the comments that tell them to *not* vandalise their posts (again),

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that would help here though. The new question was asked months after that comment, so the "last seen" would also have been.

Comment: @Larnu the first comment to that effect is from April, this new question is from September.

Comment: Yes, and the OP has made the same mistake again, and been advised, *again* to not do it, @VLAZ. Last time they were advised (by a non-mod) they went ahead and vandalised their post again.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225742) - *"They post a question, then immediately deface it once they have an answer. This is a common pattern we've observed with students who want to hide their homework from their teachers and classmates."*

Comment: Of course, it doesn't hide the answer they copied and pasted, @PeterMortensen . ;) So no matter how much they vandalise their post, the answer is still there. (And hopefully any good tutor knows how to looks at the revisions of a vandalised post on [so]).

Comment: @Larnu my point is that I don't think the "Last seen" information is useful. The OP has already been notified a few months back. It's *reasonable to assume* they've seen it. But maybe they didn't. The "Last seen" would reveal basically the same information. Don't think this really helps us. Either OP has seen the message and is *ignoring* it the message or hasn't seen it. Don't think knowing which one of this helps us much.

Comment: Then we are in disagreement, @VLAZ .

Comment: I'm actually more disappointed that [4 people](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67299743/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) have downvoted their old question today, even though it's actually very well formed. Their actions are wrong, true, but the original content quality hasn't changed. Those votes very much feel like they are for the user, not the question.

Comment: @Larnu While it is possible, it is still the case that the question "is unclear". In particular it does not define what to do when the values of the first tuple fields are different and I think that is a very valid reason to downvote and based on content.

Comment: That sounds more like a point to comment and ask for clarification, @MichaWiedenmann , not downvote.

Comment: I think it fits "the question is unclear" which matches the hover text of the downvote button.

Comment: @Larnu "Of course, it doesn't hide the answer they copied and pasted" They were aware of that and [suggested an edit vandalizing it, too](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28857616).

Comment: I wasn't aware they'd made such a suggestion, @JeanneDark , thanks.